# Can't change password and login at same time in Meteor

Tags: meteor

In my Meteor app, users are invited based on their email, then proceed to set their own password.  I want the users to land on the page and then set the password.  From there, they will be logged into the account.  I am able to set the users password, but can not log them in immediately after.

This is how I have my code:

**Client Side**

```
Meteor.call('setStudentPassword', password, id, function (error, result) {
    if (!error) {
        Meteor.loginWithPassword(id, password, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            Router.go('studentCreditCard');
        });
    }
});
```

**Server Method**

```
setStudentPassword: function(password, id) {
    if (Meteor.isServer) {
        return Accounts.setPassword(id, password);
    }
}
```

Is this possible to do, or will I need to set a temporary password on account creation?

Comment: Have you looked at [Accounts.createUser()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser) and [Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_sendenrollmentemail) docs?  This use case is described explicitly and you don't need to provide a password when creating an account on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write `Meteor.loginWithPassword(id [...])` according to [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithpassword), but have to write `Meteor.loginWithPassword({id: id} [...])` instead.

But more importantly: anyone can call the method `setStudentPassword`, and change the password for anyone. A huge security risk, I strongly advice you against using this code. Further more, the users password is sent over the wire in plain text, which should be avoided.

Comment: I see, thanks.  How would I have someone change their password securely without allowing people to call the method.

Comment: @DavidMckee, see user728291's comment in your question. Using [Accounts.resetPassword](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_resetpassword) on the client is the way to go.